# What is the Big-O time complexity of n to the power n

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity, proof-explanation

For a given positive integer $n$, what is the $O( )$ time complexity of computing $n^n$, that is, $n$ to the power $n$? I think I know the solution but wasn't sure if it was correct. My solution that I got was O(n log(n)).

Comment: Which primitive arithmetic operations are allowed?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask about the complexity of a number; one must ask about the complexity of an algorithm, and you haven't specified an algorithm. However, at some point I imagine you will have to multiply a number of size about $n^n$ (which has about $n\log n$ digits) by another number; and that isn't going to happen in constant time. So I suspect $O(n\log n)$ isn't enough.